# Nerve Theorem: Is the finite union of closed convex sets triangulable?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, computational-mathematics

**My Question:** Let $A_1, \ldots, A_k \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be closed convex sets.
Is the union $\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i$ triangulable$^1$? If so, why?

**Background:**
I'm trying to better understand the Nerve Theorem from Topology. In his Book *[Computational Topology](http://www.ee.oulu.fi/research/imag/courses/Vaccarino/Edels_Book.pdf) (p.71)* Edelsbrunner presents the following Nerve theorem without giving a proof:

> Let F be a finite collection of closed, convex sets in Euclidean Space. Then the nerve$^2$ of $F$ is homotopy equivalent to $\bigcup F$.

He also mentions the following classical nerve theorem, which one can find in *[Topological methods](http://www.math.kth.se/~bjorner/files/TopMeth.pdf) (p.1850)*, and which is supposed to be more general:

> Let $X$ be a triangulable space and let
>   $\mathcal{A} = \{A_1, \ldots, A_k\}$ be a finite closed cover$^3$ of $X$ such that
>    every non-empty intersection of the ${A_i}'s$ is contractible. Then the nerve of $\mathcal{A}$ is homotopy equivalent to $X$.

So does the former follow from the later?

$^1$ A space is called *triangulable* if it is homeomorphic to some simplicial complex.

$^2$ The *nerve* of a collection $F$ of sets is the abstract simplicial complex $\{Y \subseteq F : \bigcap Y \neq \emptyset\}$.

$^3$ A *closed cover* is a covering by closed subset of a topological space.

Comment: The definition of the nerve of F would make this question more self-contained.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this. I added the definition.

Answer (score 1):

From Taras Banakh on mathoverflow, the answer is no: https://mathoverflow.net/a/294050/38621.

The counterexample is in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with two compact convex sets, the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$ may still be open.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is a few years too late, but yes, the former follows for the latter. To see this, we need the following two things:

- convex sets are contractible
- an intersection of convex sets is convex.

From here, the former statement follows from the latter, since a collection of closed convex sets in Euclidean space is a closed cover of their union such that each non-empty intersection of the sets is contractible.

Comment: The question isn't about the cover or the contractibility conditions, but rather the part "let $X$ be a triangulable space". I shouldn't have voted "Looks OK".

Comment: Oh, wow. I completely misread the question. I was wondering why it was still unanswered.

Comment: I believe the answer is yes. First you need to show that a single closed convex set can be triangulated with simplices that are straight with respect to the standard metric on $\mathbb R^n$. Once you have this, you can triangulate a union by separately triangulating the pieces. Since both triangulations are straight, you can find a common subdivision.